# Using regular expression replace

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

In a sentence, i need to replace the space after each 5 characters into a new line in SQL is it possible?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: So you have a space after each 5 characters in the input sentence? How is that counted? Spaces at positions 6, 12, 18, ... (so the spaces themselves are not "counted" as characters)? Then... do you already have any newlines in the sentence? And just to make sure, you need to split the "sentence" into separate lines of text, and NOT into separate rows in the result set, right?

Comment: yea I need to split the "sentence" into separate lines of text. I got the result, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> replace the space after each 5 characters into a new line in SQL

This will find 5 characters then a space character and will replace the space with a new line character:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( sentence, '(.{5}) ', '\1' || CHR(10) )
FROM   your_table;
```

Comment: Thanks, but why we are  using chr(10)

Comment: chr(10) is used to new line?

Comment: `CHR(10)` is a line-feed character - so, yes, it is for a new line.